# StreamReader.ReadToEnd returns file path

Tags: c#, streamreader

I have a strange problem with StreamReader. My program is a console program and it should loop through a directory structure for all *.cs file. Then check if a specific word is in the file and write the file path to output.

```
using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(fPath))
{
    string content = sr.ReadLine(); // sr.ReadToEnd();
    Debug.WriteLine(content);
    int found = content.IndexOf(p);
    if (found != -1)
    {
        result = true;
    }
}
```

This is the code that I use to find the work in a specific file.
The problem is that sr.ReadToEnd (but also ReadLine) returns the value of *fPath* not the content of the file!

The file exists and is not locked.

If fPath is:
"C:\TEMP\DC_LV1_LaMine_Mk2Plus_134_ix220_20160404\Alarm.Script.cs"

content will be: 
"C:\TEMP\DC_LV1_LaMine_Mk2Plus_134_ix220_20160404\Alarm.Script.cs"

Can anyone see what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using **String**Reader instead of **Stream**Reader

[StringReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader(v=vs.110).aspx) implements a TextReader that reads from a *string*

[StramReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx) implements a TextReader that reads characters from a *byte stream* in a particular encoding

If you want to read from a file use this [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ke0fzy(v=vs.110).aspx) for StreamReader

You could also use [File.ReadAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext(v=vs.110).aspx) if the file is small and you have enough resources to read it all at once

For a more comprehensive overview, see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d(v=vs.110).aspx) article

Comment: I don't know how many times I have read the code and still missed this!

Comment: Sometimes you just need a fresh pair of eyes to look at it. That's why code review is a common practice!

Comment: @Andis59, please mark as answer if it helped you. Cheers!

Comment: There is a 9(10) minutes waiting period before I can mark it as Answered. But it's done now! Thanks again!